# defining struc by struct pointer

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I can't understand why after defining a struct (`sp`) with a struct pointer (`&s`), the initial struct (`s`) keeps being modified while mutating the latter (`sp`).

http://play.golang.org/p/TdcL_QJqfB

```
type person struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func main() {
    s := person{name: "Sean", age: 50}
    fmt.Printf("%p : %g\n", &s, s.age)

    sp := &s
    fmt.Printf("%p : %g\n", &sp, sp.age)

    sp.age = 51
    fmt.Printf("%p : %g\n", &sp, sp.age) // yield 51
    fmt.Printf("%p : %g\n", &s, s.age) // yields 51, but why not 50 ???
}
```

Output:

```
0xc0100360a0 : %!g(int=50)
0xc010000000 : %!g(int=50)
0xc010000000 : %!g(int=51)
0xc0100360a0 : %!g(int=51) // why not 50 ???
```

I'm new to C family language, Go and pointers, so any pointer ( :) ) to the right concept or error would be very kind of you. thanks in advance !

Comment: Because the pointer points to the same memory that your original struct does... **You requested so...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an object `s`. And a pointer `sp` that **points** to `s`. So when you set `age` through `sp`, you're actually modifying `s`.

Remember, `sp` is not a separate object. It's like an alias.

Comment: ok, got it. `sp` is only a pointer to `s`, not a copy of it. my nooby mistake. Thanks for your help @Sergio